# Estimating variance for identically non independent data

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, variance, independence, identifiability

Let $X_{ij}$ with $1\leq i<j\leq n$ (that are $X_{12},\dots, X_{1n},\dots,X_{(n-1)n}$) be ${n \choose 2}$ identically normal distributed $N(0,\sigma^2)$ such that 
$
\text{corr}(X_{ij},X_{rs})=\rho
$
if $|\{i,j\}\cap\{r,s\}|=1$ and $0$ if $|\{i,j\}\cap\{r,s\}|=0$.

I'd like to estimate $\sigma^2$ if in the large sample setting. I have proved that $\hat\sigma^2=\frac1{{n\choose 2}}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=i+1}^nX_{ij}^2$ converges to $\sigma^2$ in probability. But, how can I know that this estimator is the best estimator that we can do? For example, in the efficiency setting, do we have $\sqrt{{n\choose 2}}(\hat\sigma^2-\sigma^2)\to N(0,\tau^2)$ for some $\tau$? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the value of $\rho$ or not?  By "large sample" do you mean (as suggested in the question) that $n\to\infty$ or are you taking large iid samples of $(X_{12}, \ldots, X_{(n-1)n})$ for a fixed $n$?

Comment: Thanks @whuber for your respon. No, I don't know the value of $\rho$. Is it easier if we know the value of $\rho$? By the way, the "large sample" means $n\to \infty$.

Comment: I believe it is easier to know $\rho$, because (when $n\ge 3$) the eigenvalues of the correlation matrix are $1-2\rho$ with multiplicity $\binom{n}{2}-n$, $1+(n-4)\rho$ with multiplicity $n-1$, and $1 + 2(n-2)\rho$ with multiplicity $1$, from which you can derive a lot of information.

Comment: wow, how did you know the eigen values of the correlation matrix? I have ever tried to find them, but I stacked with the determinant calculation.